# Why is upcasting arrays allowed, while not with generics?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

The following generics code doesn't compile, and I can understand why: it's to stop potentially incompatible types being added to a collection:

```
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    objectList = stringList; // 'Incompatible types' compiler error
    // I understand the compilation error above
    // is to stop you adding incompatible types
    objectList.add(Integer.valueOf(1024));
```

However, I can do the same thing with arrays, and get no compiler error.  When I run it, I get an `ArrayStoreException`

```
    Object[] objectArray = new Object[10];
    String[] stringArray = new String[10];
    objectArray = stringArray; // No compiler error on this line
    objectArray[0] = Integer.valueOf(1024); // 'java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer' runtime error
```

Why would the compiler not stop me from doing the arrays upcast, since it goes to the trouble to stopping me doing the generics upcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed when you are trying to put incorrect type into array JVM is able to stop at runtime by throwing `ArrayStoreException`.

But in case of generics such mechanism is impossible (at least in if you are not using [checked list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList-java.util.List-java.lang.Class-)) because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) so since JVM can't stop you at runtime it stops you earlier at compilation time.